# How to convert sysdate to UTC time in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, sysdate

I am having a query to subtract a date from the sysdate. However the date object I have is in UTC but `sysdate` doesn't give me `UTC` time. How to I convert sysdate to give me date in UTC.

I have already tried using `sys_extract_utc`

```
select sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) from dual;
```

This works fine and gives me the correct UTC time stamp. But the object returned by it is not the same as `sysdate` so when I subtract date from this object I get an `INTERVAL DAY to SECOND` but it should be a number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using CAST on the result of `sys_extract_utc(systimestamp)` is the solution to this since `sys_extract_utc` returns `timestamp`.

```
select cast(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) as DATE) from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

The sys_extract_utc returns timestamp, and you are looking for date, so you just need a cast:
`select CAST(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) as DATE) from dual;`

Answer (score -1):

In case you do not want the "time" portion:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP), 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM dual;
```